# PHP swap between login/logout when user login/logout

Tags: php

Am trying to swap between login displaying username when they login (username is stored in the database) and logout when they sign out

here is my code :

```
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])): ?>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
         <?php echo $username; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
       <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: .. but? What exactly is your question?

Comment: You got no variable named `$username`. so what do you expect it to output with that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$username` is set somewhere you need to use `<?php ?>` tags to actually `echo` something:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])): ?>
  <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
  <?php echo $username; ?> 
  </li>
<?php else: ?>
  <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If `$username` is *not* set, use the session var:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])): ?>
  <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
  <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> 
  </li>
<?php else: ?>
  <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```